# Make grid have a left click command, for dynamically (programatically) generated grids

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Well I wish my custom grid (object) to "perform" something in the viewmodel. - Searching through google the correct approach to split this is to use a command, with the `Grid.InputBindings` field.

I, however, seem to be completely at a loss to get this to work. My code is as follows:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace testit
{

    public class ViewModel
    {

        public static readonly RoutedCommand ClickCommand =
            new RoutedUICommand("ClickCommand", "ClickCommand", typeof(ViewModel));
        void SelectElementCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
            // The Window gets to determine if the Foo 
            // command can execute at this time.
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
        void SelectElementExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
            // The Window executes the command logic when the user wants to Foo.
            MessageBox.Show("The Window is Fooing...");
        }
    }

    public class CustomGrid : Grid
    {
        private TextBlock tb;
        public CustomGrid(ViewModel model) {
            tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "hello world";
            Children.Add(tb); // just to show something
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);


            DataContext = model;
            var binding = new MouseBinding(ViewModel.ClickCommand,
                new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick));
            InputBindings.Add(
                binding
            );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ViewModel vm;
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            var t = Content as Grid;
            vm = new ViewModel();
            t.Children.Add(new CustomGrid(vm));
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the grid view to show a grid - and when I click on it a message box to show up. - Or at least the debugger should halt on breakpoints I put there.

Nothing seems to happen though: as if the grid is simply not correctly calling the ClickCommand. - Apparently I didn't register everything correct. What is the correct approach to do this?

For completeness, here is the xaml (though I do not wish to set the binding in a xaml file, I wish to do this programatically):

```
<Window x:Class="testit.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testit"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is the `CustomGrid` displayed correctly?
I would recommend getting familiar with DependencyProperties and "how to design" own controls. The way you are setting the `DataContext` is not the best way e.g.

Comment: Yes, and I did it this way to get the code compact to show here.

Comment: *" I wish to do this programatically"* -- is that really a requirement? You're making things much more difficult for yourself than they need to be.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes. - Are you stating things are easier when wrapped inside a usercontrol? - I did that in the past but then had lots of trouble to actually make the contained elements (' properties) of the grid visible to the one using the user control.

Comment: @paul23 On second thought, it sounds like you prefer your own way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `CommandBinding`:

```
public class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    private TextBlock tb;
    public CustomGrid(ViewModel model)
    {
        tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = "hello world";
        Children.Add(tb); // just to show something
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);


        DataContext = model;
        var binding = new MouseBinding(ViewModel.ClickCommand, new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick));
        InputBindings.Add(binding);
        var commandBinding = new CommandBinding(ViewModel.ClickCommand, SelectElementExecute);
        CommandBindings.Add(commandBinding);
    }

    void SelectElementExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The Window executes the command logic when the user wants to Foo.
        MessageBox.Show("The Window is Fooing...");
    }
}
```